# Withdrawing paper from competition track of a conference due to the fee?

Tags: conference, fees, withdraw

A few months back, I came across a competition page which asked for a solution approach for a new and tricky dataset in the domain (I will keep all the details anonymous).

Now, it was a new area of research for me, so I felt curious; interestingly I wrote a solution and submitted it. They also asked for a paper alongside the solution (the solution will be ranked based on some performance metrics) explaining the solution.

I also submitted the paper. I got acceptance email a few days back mentioning it will be added to a book series.

After the competition period, I uploaded my solution (Github) and the accepted manuscript to research-gate too (now I feel it was a mistake).

Yesterday, I got an email asking me to register for the conference with a registration fee. Now, kindly forgive my ignorance, but I was not expecting the registration fee in the competition track where the competition itself didn't have any monetary prize.

It's not that I can't pay the registration fee, but I left my lab a few years ago and currently work at a private company, now at best I'm an independent researcher without any funding. I don't feel like spending the registration fee from my own pocket for a paper that I'm not proud of and when I can not even attend the conference (due to COVID-19 situation the presentation will be online).

I applied for a grant to the committee, I'm not sure if it'll be accepted or not.

Now, should I withdraw my paper if the grant is not accepted?

Another problem I created is by uploading my accepted pre-print to the research-gate, the paper is already indexed to my google scholar profile too.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I do not see any reason why you would pay the fee.

Comment: Are you sure this is an academic conference?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes, the main conference is a trusted one. They launched a competition track under the main conference, in which I submitted the paper.

Comment: Did the competition advert make it clear that a fee would need to be paid? You may just have to write this off to experience. Or consult a lawyer.

Comment: No, nothing regarding a registration fee was mentioned. But from my experience, usually, a registration fee is needed to register a paper in a conference (minimum one author registration who'll present the paper). But this is a confusing scenario that's why I can't decide. 1. I solely focused on the competition and my code, the paper only complemented it. 2. They are somewhat right on their point as paper registration requires a fee but here it was not mentioned in the competition page and also now I can't even attend. 3. I really don't want to go the hard way, something minimal from my side.

Comment: You say you are not proud of the paper - is that just so you can withdraw it? But you have gone and made it public with research gate and your scholar profile... What are you doing?

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted it. It's still valid work, but as I told I more focused on the coding part (the solution tricks) rather than a clean, detailed academic paper. (competition papers are short, less theoretical especially in my field (machine learning)) I made it public because the source code and the paper will be definitely helpful but I don't want to pay for that (that's what I meant). I had the thought I didn't have to pay any fee or anything so I can make the work public as the work is accepted. I hope you understand.

Comment: Adding accepted pre-prints to arxiv/research-gate is a common trend, google scholar indexed it automatically. If let's say, they decline my grant, I withdraw the paper, but the paper stays on the researchgate, google scholar will that be an issue for me? I'm kind of worried about that.

Comment: A competition track is like a regular track or workshop track of a conference. Of course, there are typically registration fees, although, post-Covid, they should be smaller or could be entirely waived due to being online. So, the question is why you expected (pre-Covid) to not have to pay registration. Someone has to organise location, computers, setup etc. But yes, you can withdraw.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs yes, I know. I agree it was my ignorance and fault on my side, that's why I don't blame them but it was my first time participating on a competition track so I should have emailed them asking if a fee is needed (there were no details about the fee on the competition page). But if I attended the conference, I probably wouldn't hesitate that much. Now, the situation is different. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If the competition is held like a workshop in CS conferences, there may be a separate workshop-only registration option that is much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to attend the conference, request that the paper be withdrawn. I doubt you can undo posting of the content on the internet. In the future, do ask if all presenters must pay registration fees, even those in the competition. This is often the case and may be stated somewhere in the information about the conference.